# \pgflinewidth as option in arrows.meta arrows heads

Tags: tikz-arrows

i try to define arrow's head size by using ˙\pgflinewidth`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0cm,0cm) grid ($(2cm,3cm)-(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);       % this works

\draw[very thick, -{Triangle[length=3\pgflinewidth]}] (0,0) -- (2,3);   % this doesn't work!
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

error: `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`.

what is wrong in my attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Triangle[length=3*\the\pgflinewidth]
```

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0cm,0cm) grid ($(2cm,3cm)-(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$);       % this works

\draw[very thick, -{Triangle[length=3*\the\pgflinewidth]}] (0,0) -- (2,3);   % this doesn't work!
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### EDIT

The same output can be obtained with the following line also:

```
\draw[very thick, -{Triangle[length=0pt 3]}] (0,0) -- (2,3);
```

Comment: May be a bit of an explanation would add great value to this answer!

Comment: this  solution not cause error, however,  arrows head is far to big (about 8 times). this means that it not consider width of used rule.

Comment: @Zarko I don't know why it is like that. But replacing `3\the\pgflinewidth` with `3*\the\pgflinewidth` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @nidhin, thank you very much. now works correctly..

Comment: @Zarko You can actually use `Triangle[length=0pt 3]` to get the desired output.

Comment: @nidhin, huh, i test this before send my question, but I didn't get the right result then. now this work ... (quite embarrassing :-(). thank you very much! please add this solution to answer.